# How to write regular expression for the given situation

Tags: java, regex

I am working on generating a configuration file from a template. The template looks something like:

```
$Country$$Country$
WAN$Country$/$Country$
$Country$/29
$Country$/$Country$
"$fdfsrwdrdgf$1$asffdjhk"
```

This is just a sample. I consider anything between two `$`s as a placeholder. So in the above example `Country` is the only placeholder I need. I am using the below regular expression in Java code:

```
{"\\$[^$]*\\$";}
```

Now, the problem I have is, I do not want anything inside quotes to be recognised with the above RE, or rather I want to change the RE such that it ignores the content inside quotes (`""`). Could anyone please help me with it?

Comment: [`(?<notThis>"[^"]+")|(?<IWantThis>\$[^$]*\$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xE7wA4/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Best Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#notarzan):

> You remember the simple case where we tried to match all instances of Tarzan except those enclosed in double quotes?... Well, you'll now see how simple the problem becomes when you use the best regex trick ever:
>
> `"Tarzan"|(Tarzan)`
>
> Really? That's it?
>
> Yes. The trick is that **we match what we don't want on the left side of the alternation** (the `|`), **then we capture what we do want on the right side**. When our programming language returns the results, we ignore the overall matches (that's the trash bin) and instead turn our whole attention to Group 1 matches, which contain what we were after.

So, all you need is

```
"[^"]+"|(\$[^$]*\$)
```

Or (if you have escape sequences:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|(\$[^$]*\$)
```

And get the contents of the capturing group #1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR8bE2/1).

[Demo](http://ideone.com/75ydkN):

```
String s = "$Country$$Country$\nWAN$Country$/$Country$\n$Country$/29\n$Country$/$Country$\n\"$fdfsrwdrdgf$1$asffdjhk\""; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\\"]*)*\"|(\\$[^$]*\\$)"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        res.add(matcher.group(1)); 
        //                    ^  - Get Group 1 only! 
    }
} 
System.out.println(res);
// => [$Country$, $Country$, $Country$, $Country$, $Country$, $Country$, $Country$]
```

Comment: Thanks so much For such a detailed explanation! It works!